# Проблемы с кодировкой при переносе значения из поля blob в varchar

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Я создала дамп таблицы из одной бд и пыталась вставить данные из этого файла в таблицу похожей структуры. Данные вставились, но я получила warning:

> Warning Code : 1366 Incorrect string value:
>   '\xC7\xE4\xE0\xED\xE8\xE5...' for column 'placement' at row 1

И в поле `placement` вместо текста на русском языке вставились кракозябры типа:

> "??? 05/03 ?????"

В старой бд это поле было определено как:

```
`placement` blob
```

а в новой как:

```
`placement` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

В схемах обеих бд, и старой, и новой, как кодировка по умолчанию указана `cp1251`:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

При этом, когда я открываю файл дампа как тестовый файл, текст этого поля выводится в нормальной виде. В чём проблема и как это исправить?

**UPD**
Кажется, проблема в том, как читает файл дампа *SQLyog*, потому что после открытия файла в окне *SQLyog* я вижу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле `BLOB` не имеет кодировки и хранит данные "как есть".

Вам нужно ответить на два вопроса:

1. В какой кодировке у Вас лежали данные в блобе?
2. Какая кодировка у Вас используется для импорта в БД?

Для Вашей ситуации эти две кодировки должны совпадать.

Я подозреваю, что данные в блобе у Вас лежали в cp1251, а кодировка подключения у Вас utf-8. Тогда просто обрамите импорт проблемной таблицы двумя командами

```
SET NAMES cp1251;
INSERT INTO ....
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Но это все будет работать если в таблице нет других текстовых полей